# How to set IP Address of Network adapters?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, process, ip-address

I have to change IP address very frequently for playing LAN games as well as for using internet at home. I am creating an application in C# which can do it quickly. I have made fields like Adapter Name, IP Address, Subnet, DNS Server Address.
My code which runs on set IP button click is below:

```
string adapter = comboAdapterName.Text;
string ip = comboIPAddress.Text;
string subnet = comboSubnet.Text;
string dns = comboDNS.Text;
```

Now I want to use this process method for taking data from those fields and append the string accordingly.

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", "interface ip set address \"Local Area Connection\" static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1");
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();
```

But I guess it is not so easy. Because I am unable to edit this without disturbing the format. Also I tried creating a whole new string using many +s which i can place like:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(mystring);
```

But still it is too difficult for me. Please suggest an easy way to do this.

==========================================================================

I think I got it:

```
string ipstring = "netsh interface ip set address " + "\"" + adapter + "\"" + " " + "static" + " " + ip + " " + subnet + " " + dns;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b1csw23d.aspx%20String.Format) method.

Example:

```
string subnet = comboSubnet.Text;

string formatted = string.Format("Subnet is: {0}", subnet);

MessageBox.Show(formatted);
```

Format that string to look like whatever you want.

Comment: In what way? The poster is asking to concatinate strings and says it's "too difficult for him". He cannot build his string from parts he already has. String.Format is the way to build a string from parts you already have.

Comment: Actually I was unable to add " in my string. What a stupidity. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current adapter config with following function:

```
private static void EthernetInf(out string ip, out string dns, out string nic)  // To get current ethernet config
{
    ip = "";
    dns = "";
    nic = "";
    foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        if (ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
        {

            foreach (IPAddress dnsAdress in ni.GetIPProperties().DnsAddresses)
            {
                if (dnsAdress.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    dns = dnsAdress.ToString();
                }
            }



            foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ips in ni.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
            {
                if (ips.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork && !ips.Address.ToString().StartsWith("169")) //to exclude automatic ips
                {
                    ip = ips.Address.ToString();
                    nic = ni.Name;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Following Function is used to set the IP in elevated command prompt:

```
private void SetIP(Button sender, string arg)  //To set IP with elevated cmd prompt
{
    try
    {
        if (sender.Background == Brushes.Cyan )
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Already Selected...");
            return;
        }
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
        psi.UseShellExecute = true;
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        psi.Verb = "runas";
        psi.Arguments = arg;
        Process.Start(psi);
        if (sender == EthStatic ||  sender == EthDHCP )
        {
            EthStatic.ClearValue(Button.BackgroundProperty);
            EthDHCP.ClearValue(Button.BackgroundProperty);

            sender.Background = Brushes.Cyan;
         }

        if (sender == WIFIStatic || sender == WIFIDhcp)
        {
            WIFIStatic.ClearValue(Button.BackgroundProperty);
            WIFIDhcp.ClearValue(Button.BackgroundProperty);

            sender.Background = Brushes.Cyan;
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

    }
```

This click button code passes the arguments to processstartinfo to set the IP

```
private void EthStatic_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    SetIP(EthStatic, "/c netsh interface ip set address \"" + EthName + "\" static " + Properties.Settings.Default.EthIPac + " " + Properties.Settings.Default.Subnet + " " + Properties.Settings.Default.EthDnsac + " & netsh interface ip set dns \"" + EthName + "\" static " + Properties.Settings.Default.EthDnsac);


}
```

The complete app is available at:

https://github.com/kamran7679/ConfigureIP